# How do I translate a spherical coordinate to a Cartesian one?

Tags: c#, geometry, coordinates

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how this might be achieved? 3D math / geometry often throws me.

I'm looking for something like this (ideally in C#):

```
public Vector3 getCartesianFor(float elevation, float asimuth, float polar)
{
   return ????;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/10/22/spherical-coordinates-in-unity/

```
public static void SphericalToCartesian(float radius, float polar, float elevation, out Vector3 outCart){
    float a = radius * Mathf.Cos(elevation);
    outCart.x = a * Mathf.Cos(polar);
    outCart.y = radius * Mathf.Sin(elevation);
    outCart.z = a * Mathf.Sin(polar);
}


public static void CartesianToSpherical(Vector3 cartCoords, out float outRadius, out float outPolar, out float outElevation){
    if (cartCoords.x == 0)
        cartCoords.x = Mathf.Epsilon;
    outRadius = Mathf.Sqrt((cartCoords.x * cartCoords.x)
                    + (cartCoords.y * cartCoords.y)
                    + (cartCoords.z * cartCoords.z));
    outPolar = Mathf.Atan(cartCoords.z / cartCoords.x);
    if (cartCoords.x < 0)
        outPolar += Mathf.PI;
    outElevation = Mathf.Asin(cartCoords.y / outRadius);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what was after ... just need to figure out how to do this without the unity math libs ... any recommends on math libs for .Net ... or is this built in somewhere? I could only see these functions for doubles.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

[image]

- `r`: radial distance
- `θ`: inclination
- `φ`: azimuth

*via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)*

```
public Vector3 getCartesianFor(float radius, float inclination, float azimuth)
{
   return new Vector3(radius*Sin(inclination)*Cos(azimuth), radius*Sin(inclination)*Sin(azimuth), radius*Cos(inclination));
}
```

[image: Spherical coordinates]

Comment: You should elaborate about the meanings of the (literal) Greek in your answer.

Comment: @SethBattin Thank you for the suggestion! The answer has been updated.

Comment: What you call *inclination* is probably the *complement* of what OP means for *elevation*, ie. the angle from the xy plane to the vector, not from vector to the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

If by `polar` you mean the magnitude of the vector, and `elevation` is defined as the angle between vector and the xy plane (as the name implies), the function would be:

```
public Vector3 getCartesianFor(float elevation, float asimuth, float polar)
{
   return new Vector3(polar*Cos(elevation)*Cos(asimuth),
                      polar*Cos(elevation)*Sin(asimuth),
                      polar*Sin(inclination));
}
```

Note that this is very similar to MLM's answer, it all depends on how you define your `elevation` angle. I've also respected your function template signature, but I suggest a few changes:

- `asimuth` is a typo, the correct spelling would be `azimuth`
- `polar` usually refers to the 2D coordinate *system* (r, θ). The magnitude of the vector is commonly referred to as `radius`
- A more conventional order would have `radius` as the first parameter.