# Combine rotation XZ (horizontal) with YZ (vertical). Math formula

Tags: mathematics, rotation, matrix, three.js, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a rotation vertically and horizontally around a point at the same time but I'm not able to combine both.

I have this formula for the horizontal rotation:

```
camera.position.x = x * Math.cos(inc) + z * Math.sin(inc)
camera.position.z = z * Math.cos(inc) - x * Math.sin(inc)
```

And this one for the vertical:

```
camera.position.y = y * Math.cos(inc) + z * Math.sin(inc)
camera.position.z = z * Math.cos(inc) - y * Math.sin(inc)
```

I guess I need to use a Matrix, but not sure how. Here an example with Three.js:
https://codepen.io/josema/pen/xyQoga

Comment: Are you just looking to convert a point in spherical coordinates (an azimuth angle in the horizontal plane and an altitude/polar angle off the horizontal) into a vector in Cartesian coordinates? If so, do [previous questions about spherical coordinates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81713/how-do-i-translate-a-spherical-coordinate-to-a-cartesian-one) cover what you need?

Comment: I already have the two rotations working individually. I'm just trying to combine them, but don't know how to make the formula.

Comment: Do the formulas at the link above solve that problem? If not, can you describe in detail what behaviour you need that's not provided by those answers?

Comment: Imagine the horizontal rotation is permanent, and the vertical is controlled with the mouse. I just did a small change here https://codepen.io/josema/pen/xyQoga in case that helps you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DMGregory mentioned above what I really needed was a way to translate a polar/spherical coordinates into cartesian coordinates.

In other words, I have two angles and one radius and I need to convert it into a Vector3/XYZ.

Here is the code:

```
function polarToCartesian( angleV, angleH, radius ) {

  var phi = ( 90 - angleV ) * DEG2RAD
  var theta = ( angleH + 180 ) * DEG2RAD

  return {
    x: -(radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta)),
    y: radius * Math.cos(phi),
    z: radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta),
  }

}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jhermsmeier/72626d5fd79c5875248fd2c1e8162489